# In-App Purchase basic app with additional premium features app in iOS

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I'm trying to create an application with IAP enabled. As for testing I'm creating a sample application first.

What I need to do is releasing a small size application with minimum features first and if user willing to use extra features she needs to use IAP.

My question is, how can I link my full feature application inside my basic application ?

If I clarify the situation more, I only need to have single application visible in App Store with the name of "MyAppName" and it is the basic application. So where do I need to upload my Product app source code?

In iTunes Connect I have added the details for my basic app (MyAppName). In the Features category, I have given details to my Product app. But I'm not clear where is the related code should be uploaded for review.

Is the Product means, a different app with different Bundle ID that I need to add to iTunes connect as a New App?

My Product is not some assets but some code related to Augmented Reality and it's related libraries.

According to [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Chapters/DeliverProduct.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008267-CH5-SW21) I think my scenario is downloading the whole new application with enabled features from Apple's Server.

I hope you guys can understand the scenario now. Hope this can be implement.

Comment: You only have one app that contains all features. You use logic to disable/enable feature based on whether the iAp has been made

Comment: Hi @Paulw11, is that mean I need to add those my Augmented Reality features in the basic app and let the user download the whole app? After user tap to activate IAP, I should enable those AR features in the application? If that's the scenario, that I can understand. But then the my application size will be increased considerably. I wanted to avoid that situation since I thought when the app is large users will less likely to download it from App Store.

Comment: That is how it works - there is only one app.

Comment: Thanks @Paulw11. You could have put this as an answer with some details. Then I would accept it. Anyway, I've upvote your comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways to achieve your goal.

1. Put a single app and implement in-app purchase to provide extra features. If user purchase in-app purchase in app then hidden feature would be available to them.

   - For this option, you have to upload app with all your features but user would able to access some of desire features after purchasing of IAP.
2. Put two apps on store. One app with limited features and second app with full features.

   - You may set different price for both apps as per your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

There will be the only one app with one binary source code to upload at appstore. You have to setup the IAP features manually. you have to keep a track of users, who has purchased your additional features or not.
Whenever user purchases your additional feature, you manually have to enable the additional feature to be accessed by that user.
You can keep a track of users purchased history by keeping a users data to server.
 Please read the IAP documentations for more IAP options.